It's supposed to be a MOD10 counter but it counts from 0 to 9 and resets to 4. Why?
It's supposed to be a MOD10 counter, but it counts from 0 to 9 and resets to 4.  Why?  Please give me the solution as a code and explanation for it if possible.
module MOD10 (clk, clr, q);
    input clk, clr;
    output [3:0] q;
   
    wire x, w;
  
    assign x = q[3] & q[1];  // Detects when the count reaches 10 (binary 1010)
    assign w = x | clr;      // Reset or clear condition
  
    TFF tff1(clk, w, 1'b1, q[0]);  // First TFF for q[0]
    TFF tff2(q[0], w, 1'b1, q[1]); // Second TFF for q[1]
    TFF tff3(q[1], w, 1'b1, q[2]); // Third TFF for q[2]
    TFF tff4(q[2], w, 1'b1, q[3]); // Fourth TFF for q[3]
endmodule

module TFF (clk, clr, t, q);
    input clk, clr, t;
    output reg q;
  
    always @(posedge clr or negedge clk) begin
        if (clr)
            q <= 0;  // Clear or reset the flip-flop
        else begin
            if (!t)
                q <= q;  // Maintain the state when T = 0
            else
                q <= ~q; // Toggle the output when T = 1
        end
    end
endmodule

module MOD10_TB();
    reg clk, clr;
    wire [3:0] q;
  
  // Instantiate the MOD10 module
    MOD10 uut (clk, clr, q);
  
  // Clock signal generation (50% duty cycle)
    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;  // Toggle clock every 5 time units
    end
  
  // Reset logic and test sequence
    initial begin
        clr = 1;  // Reset active
        #10 clr = 0;  // Deactivate reset after 10 time units
        #110 $finish;  // End simulation after 110 time units
    end
endmodule


It's supposed to be a MOD10 counter, so I expected for it to count from 0 to 9 and reset to 0 again, but it counts from 0 to 9 and resets to 4.

Glitches on the clock input to the tff3 instance cause the undesired result.  I was able to clearly see the glitch in waveforms using the Synopsys VCS simulator.
Your code does not follow good design practices.  For synchronous designs, all flops should use the same clock signal, but your code uses several clock signals.
Here is code that does what you want:
module MOD10 (clk, clr, q);
    input clk, clr;
    output reg [3:0] q;
   
    always @(posedge clr or negedge clk) begin
        if (clr) begin
            q <= 0;  // reset the counter
        end else if (q == 9) begin
            q <= 0;  // reset when count is 9
        end else begin
            q <= q + 1;
       end
    end  
endmodule

It is always best to model at the highest level of abstraction.  Instead of creating toggle flops, just create a simple counter.
